# How to read the Windows Event Log without an EventMessageFile?

Tags: event-log, eventlog-source, formatmessage, readeventlog

I have code that reads the Windows Event Log.  It uses OpenEventLog, ReadEventLog and gets the event source and event ID.  Then it looks up the source under the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application
```

key, loads the appropriate DLL(s) according to what is listed in `EventMessageFile` and finally uses `FormatMessage` to merge the event strings with the message DLL content to get the final event message text.  This is the recommended way, and although a bit of a pain, it works great.

Until... I go lookup the source and find it doesn't have an `EventMessageFile`, but rather a `ProvideGuid` entry.  This seems to be the new way (they show up on Vista and Windows 2008).  Uggh -- nothing to pass to FormatMessage for looking up the message text and merging in the data strings

:(

Searching the registry for the guid does lead to references to other files (http.sys in the case of the HTTP source), but I can never get the complete message text.  Do I have to use those `EvtOpenSession` APIs?  I'm hoping not since I already have the `EVENTLOGRECORD*` from a call to `ReadEventLog`, and the fact that the software needs to run on Windows 2003 where `EvtOpenSession` isn't supported (only available on Vista and Windows 2008).  NOTE: Some sources on Vista have ProviderGUID, and others have EventMessageFile, so the old method is still viable.

So what I'm after is a way to look at the ProviderGuid and get the DLL that needs to be passed to FormatMessage for displaying the complete event log message text.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs that Richard links to are for the new style Eventing system (code-named Crimson, sometimes called Manifest Based Providers) introduced in Vista/Server 2K8.  One of the artifacts of this new system is new APIs to consume these logs, another is the ProviderGuid key for certain EventSources that produce events using this new framework.

I think you should use the functions on Windows Vista later to consume these logs, it should handle the work for you.  You can use the EvtFormatMessage method to format the strings.  I believe these APIs will also read the events produced by "Classic" providers.

If you're consuming these messages from a .NET app you can use types in the System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader namespace, introduced in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Does that mean an app (the Windows Event Log Viewer for instance) running on a Win2003 machine can't read the events from a Vista machine that uses a new provider?

Answer (score 1):

There are Win32 APIs for reading/expanding event log entries.

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780(VS.85).aspx

Anything else, and you are likely to find problems with patches, let alone service packs or new versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, those APIs only work on Vista and Windows Server 2008 :(

Comment: May have the wrong link. APIs exist to read the event log in earlier versions of Windows also. (Vista/Win2k8 got the first overhaul of the Event Logging system since WinNT3.1).

Comment: Right.  And those APIs are what I'm using (OpenEventLog, ReadEventLog, etc).  However, they pre-suppose that you can load the event source's message file in order to call FormatMessage.  If you can't find the file, you can't get the complete event message :(